# jmeter ${__threadNum} does not render when passed through command line argument

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-4.0

I am working on setting up a jmeter load test, where each simulated user would submit reference to their own unique content source. For that reason, at the beginning of each test, I am creating a new folder structure, where the path include a number reference to each simulated user.

That number is planned to correspond to the jmeter `${__threadNum}` value.

Once the test is running, each simulated user would send a POST request to an API endpoint, where the body of the request would contain the absolute path to every file that is in any given users' directory.

Example:
If the test simulates two users, I would create the following folder structure:

```
/storage
  /testfiles_user1
    test_file_1
    test_file_2
  /testfiles_user2
    test_file_1
    test_file_2
```

Then for each user the POST request would have the following `JSON` in the request body:

For user1:

```
{
  "files": [
             "/storage/testfiles_user1/test_file_1",
             "/storage/testfiles_user1/test_file_2"
           ]
}
```

For user2:

```
{
  "files": [
             "/storage/testfiles_user2/test_file_1",
             "/storage/testfiles_user2/test_file_2"
           ]
}
```

Here comes my problem.

When I hardcode this path in the HTTP request body, calling `${__threadNum}`, in the following way

```
{
  "files": [
             "/storage/testfiles_user${__threadNum}/test_file_1",
             "/storage/testfiles_user${__threadNum}/test_file_2"
           ]
}
```

then everything works as expected => the paths are updated with the `${__threadNum}` variable value, producing the following two `JSON`:

For user1:

```
{
  "files": [
             "/storage/testfiles_user1/test_file_1",
             "/storage/testfiles_user1/test_file_2"
           ]
}
```

For user2:

```
{
  "files": [
             "/storage/testfiles_user2/test_file_1",
             "/storage/testfiles_user2/test_file_2"
           ]
}
```

However when I try to pass the HTTP request body JSON as a command line argument, `${__threadNum}` is rendered within the path as normal text and not considered as a variable by jmeter, producing the following two `JSON`:
For user1:

```
{
  "files": [
             "/storage/testfiles_user${__threadNum}/test_file_1",
             "/storage/testfiles_user${__threadNum}/test_file_2"
           ]
}
```

For user2:

```
{
  "files": [
             "/storage/testfiles_user${__threadNum}/test_file_1",
             "/storage/testfiles_user${__threadNum}/test_file_2"
           ]
}
```

Do you have any suggestion how to resolve this problem? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve JMeter Variables in files or passed via command-line arguments you need to wrap your call into [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval)

For example, if you previously had `${__P(foo,)}` you will need to replace it with `${__eval(${__P(foo,)})}` - this way nested [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) will be called.

Demo:

[image: JMeter Combine JMeter Variables]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)